# Is sshfs over the internet safe?

Tags: encryption, sshfs

I'd like to try sshfs for accessing my Nextcloud files on the command-line. I've used dav2fs but it's a bit slow to connect; for example, executing the command `ls` on a directory mounted with dav2fs takes a couple of seconds.

Since my Nextcloud instance is over a HTTPS connection, it is safe to use over the internet (outside of local IPs).

Is sshfs safe to use over the network? For example, I ssh into my server on my phone on mobile data using `username@myawesomewebsite.com`. So I would mount sshfs with that URL and user (and of course the directory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, SSHFS is safe to use over public Internet. Internally it uses the SSH File Transfer Protocol, which requires an existing SSH session to be set up, so you get all the security benefits of “regular” SSH in terms of authentication and encryption.

That said, you want to make sure you enable some basic security features such as:

- No password-based authentication; use key-based authentication instead.
- Create a separate user just for SFTP file transfers. The user should be `chroot`ed into a directory from where it cannot access any system files. [Example setup here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes).